# Why do i get blue image as output?

Tags: image, qt, opencv

Why do i get blue image as output of this code:

```
imgq = QImage((uchar*)imagee.data, imagee.cols, imagee.rows,imagee.cols*3,QImage::Format_RGB888);
pixel = QPixmap::fromImage(imgq);
ui->label_pic->setPixmap(pixel);
```

Comment: because OpenCV order is BGR, while Qt is RGB. Use `cvtColor(imagee, imagee, COLOR_BGR2RGB);` before

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV uses `BGR` by default. You are using `QImage::Format_RGB888`, so the channels blue and red are inverted.

To fix this you can use in OpenCV the [`cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) function

```
cv::cvtColor(imagee, imagee, CV_BGR2RGB);
```

before the code you showed.

That is the easiest way...

Comment: @JanakLal If your question is solved accept the answer, this will help future users to know that it worked.